# How do I edit the raw value of a property using a PUT request in Java?

Tags: java, json, get, put

I'm able to edit properties as KV pair via json.

```
        HttpPut putRequest = new HttpPut(url);
        putRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        putRequest.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        keyArg.put("key","value");
        StringEntity input;
        try {
            input = new StringEntity(keyArg.toString());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Success";
        }
        putRequest.setEntity(input);
```

I want to be able to edit the value of the property at the url. A GET request at *"url?raw"* returns me the value of the property. A GET request at *"url"* returns a response with key value pairs as

**[{"param1":"value1","param2":"value2","param3":"value3","param4":"value4"}]**

**EDIT:** I was able to achieve this by using the okhttp Code provided in Postman

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "1");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url(url+"?raw=")
  .put(body)
  .addHeader("accept", "application/json")
  .addHeader("content-type", "text/plain")
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .addHeader("postman-token", "aca42ee1-073d-8e3d-cdeb-4e68e8e8b48a")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: Can you explain more what are you trying to achieve? If I get it correctly you want to have PATCH functionality..